# Elements combination in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a question, I need to build a function whose output is a matrix for all possible combination between one element which is repeated just one time and the other element can be one or more.

For example, suppose we have the array y with dimension of 3 x 1, initialized [0 0 0] the first element is x which is repeated just one time, and the second element r which is repeated either one or more. so the resulted matrix I need to build will be similar to that one:

```
y = [x r 0; 
     x 0 r;
     x r r;
     r x 0;
     0 x r;
     r x r;
     r 0 x;
     0 r x;
     r r x]
```

I tried using the `nchoosek`, but that doesn't work because when I have [x r 0], I can't have [x 0 r].

I tried this example with permutation, but I couldn't put now x in the location of 3, and r in location of 0 according to the above matrix

```
clear all 
clc 

v = 1 : 3; 
vv = perms(v); 
vv(vv<3)=0;
```

please your help.

thank you

Comment: Your example is confusing. You say that the first element is `x` and that it is repeated just one time, but actually it appears three times. Please post a clear example with actual numbers

Comment: Have you tried writing some code that does this? It doesn't seem particularly hard. Well, the example you put would throw an error in MATLAB , I assume you made some typos there

Comment: @LuisMendo .. in each combination the element x is repeated once, and the other element r which is changing, and the element x is repeated three times, but in each time either with changing the position of r or with r is repeated more than once

Comment: @AnderBiguri I tried but I get problems ! .. I couldn't. could you please help?

Comment: @New_student show us what you tried

Comment: @AnderBiguri, I tried using nchoosek, but that didn't work at all, because when having the combination [x r 0], I can't have the inverse [r x 0],  please if you can help in that point, or give suggestion, That will be appreciated.

Comment: @AnderBiguri .. Let me check it. I'm trying to understand how to works, I will let you know when I finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a tricky problem. This is how I solved it:

1. Assume you have 2 `r`: `r1`,`r2`.
2. Compute all permutations
3. Remove the equivalent ones (where `r1` is in place of `r2` and vice versa)
4. Remove the ones you dont like (the ones without `x`)

In the end you have it in "code mode", you just need to replace the numbers by the corresponding variable. I am sure you can figure that one out ;)

```
% Code is:
% x=1
% r=2
% r=3
% 0=4
nk=nchoosek(1:4,3);

% compute all permutations
fullperms=[];
for ii=1:size(nk,1)
    fullperms=[fullperms; perms(nk(ii,:))];
end

% Remove the ones that are "the same" (we have 2 r)
% eg
% [1 2 4] and [1 3 4]
fullpermsaux=fullperms;
fullpermsaux(fullpermsaux==2)=3;
[~,ia,~]=unique(fullpermsaux,'rows');
fullperms=fullperms(ia,:);

% Remove the ones that have no "x"
fullperms(~any(fullperms'==1)',:)=[];

% Tada!

% Replace numbers as:
% x=1
% r=2
% r=3
% 0=4
```

Comment: Thanks bro .. that works well. To be honest, The results are working well, but I still try to understand the way it works in order to replace the numbers as you said. thanks again :)

Comment: Yes, that's good. I got it now. but I'd like to put it in a function. Regarding that step of `nk=nchoosek(1:4,3);`, what is the 4 and what is the 3? is the 4 the dimension of resulted matrix y plus one, and the 3 is the biggest number of variables we can have, such as x r r?  could you please clarify? Because I will need next step to build the same thing for 4 dimension, it means [x r 0 0], an then till [x r r r], so the function will be preferred for that code.

Comment: @New_student 4 is the variables (`[x,r1,r2,0]`), and 3 is how elements you want in each row. If `[x r r r]` is an option, then you need to include a 3rd `r`, `r3`, so increment the amount of variables.

Comment: Yes I see .. but can we put it as variable? I mean the 4 and 3, and then put then in a function?

Comment: @New_student yes, I assume you can, nothing hinting you can not.

Comment: Hello @Ander Biguri .. Yes that worked well. thanks again. But I have a question, what's the mathematical relationship between the number of columns and number of possible combination? Example, for 4 columns, we should have 28 possible combination, for 3 columns, we should have 9 possible combination so so on. Is there  mathematical relationship which specifies that? thanks again.